# What's the worst sequence that still leads to a converging series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, polylogarithm

As a background, I'm initially interested in sequences $a_n$ giving rise to functions $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and their diverging behavior for $x$ to $1$. E.g. the geometric series $a_n=1$, giving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Consider $a_n:=n^{-s}$ (including, for negative integers $s$, monomials). For complex $\mid\,x\mid<1$, the polylogarithm
$${\mathrm{Li}}_s(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n^{-s}}x^n$$
converges.
Consider now an exponential $a_n:=d^{-n}$ with $d\in(0,1)$. We get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{d^{-n}}x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{x}{d}\right)^n$$

Looking at the geometric series, we see that this shrinks the domain for $x$ to $(0,d)$.

Question: What are there for $a_n$ that grow faster than a polynomial in $n$, but still leave the domain for the polylogarithm, at least on the real axis, untouched?

Comment: The title and the body ask two quite different questions; please resolve the discrepancy. The answer to the question in the title is "There isn't one.", since you can always increase a finite number of terms of the sequence without changing the convergence.

Comment: @joriki: How do you read "worst"? I didn't know how to make the quesiton sufficiently precise in less than twelve words.

Comment: "Worst" means the one which is maximally bad, more than any other one.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Ah, k. What's the property of the element on the other side of the order?